# Функция внутри .addEventListener может вызвать только alert(), на остальное никак не реагирует

Tags: javascript

Я только недавно начал работать с JS и HTML и наткнулся на очень странную проблему: в content.js есть листенер клика по кнопке из popup.html расширения гугл, листенер спокойно обрабатывает клик, но может вызвать только функцию alert() после клика, на другие функции не реагирует и ошибок не выдает. Понятия не имею с чем это может быть связано, может я чего-то не знаю о работе JS?

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
    btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    console.log("123") // ничего не выведет
    alert("123") // сработает алерт
    })
})
```

```css
body {
  min-width: 200px;
  min-height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Текст" id="myInput" size="30">
<button id="btn">Клик</button>
```

Comment: Странно... У меня всё выводит и в консоль и в alert ?

Comment: Вы какого поведения ожидаете от console.log() ?

Comment: Вероятно, Вы ожидаете сперва вывод console.log а потом alert?

Comment: Ничего странного, у расширений так сказать свои "вкладки", если вы бы делали `console.log` в скрипте которые работают в `background` (Такие скрипты указываются manifest), то всё бы заработало. К слову на консоль расширения (то есть popup'a) можно посмотреть в `about:debugging` (для Firefox), заходите в "This Firefox", выбираете нужное расширение и нажимаете "Inspect".

Comment: @ΝNL993 Да, вы правы, но как только я пытаюсь использовать этот же листенер в background, он мне выдает ошибку(кнопку неоткуда брать).

Comment: @addavriance Изучайте тему подробнее прежде чем браться за проект! `background` скрипты - для работы на странице, обыкновенные - для popup'a. Если нужно передать какие-то данные с `background` скриптов или наоборот с обыкновенных, используйте Storage API для расширений (`browser.storage`...). То есть, в `content.js` накладываете слушатель, сохраняете строку которую нужно передать в `background.js` для `console.log` и уже в самом `background.js` с хранилища берёте строку и логируйте её. Ничего сложного.

Comment: @ΝNL993 Ладненько, спасибо за помощь!